# remove matched items found in for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, indexof, splice

Im doing a search through an object data response and detecting if it includes '*wdt*'.. This works fine; however I am struggling to destroy or ***remove*** the found items from being processed with my `data`.

*Don't believe there is an effective single keyword like **delete** to do this in JavaScript?*

I am trying `splice` currently, however it doesn't seem effective. Still finding the items in my `console.log(data);`

```
let data = await getData(); 

filterChkpt();

function filterChkpt(){
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (data[i].url.indexOf('wdt') > -1) {
          console.log(data[i]);

          data[i].splice(index, 1); // here would like to remove matches

      } else {
         // console.log('else: ', data[i].url);
      }
    }
  }

  console.log(data);

  if (!this.data) {
    this.data = {};
  }

  this.data.storage = new Memory({ data });

  return this;
```

Comment: Try removing `[i]` from `data[i].splice(index, 1)`

Comment: Unless there's some reason you need to mutate the original object, this is what [`array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is for. (And it spooks me to modify the object _while_ iterating over it.)

Comment: Thanks.. I tried that too (removing i).. unsure why though? Because I can update values in the if statement with data[i].id = "404"; for instance...

Comment: Could you recreate the problem with some data and working example?

Comment: @RainbowRandolph Added an answer with a demo snippet below. If you needed to modify the objects in question you could chain a [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) call after filter.

Comment: Create a new object and add the values which you won't remove. I thinking is the best options because you modifying the length from the same variable use in your **for**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there's some reason you need to mutate the original object, this is what [array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is for. (And it spooks me to modify the object while iterating over it.)

```js
const data = Array.from({length: 10}, () => ({ url: Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'foo' : 'bar' }));

console.log(data);
console.log(data.filter(x => x.url === 'foo'));
```

Comment: Thanks.. what is the length 10 in regards to? Also, I'm searching for a value that contains a piece of text, i.e. wdt not the whole word hardcoded.

Comment: The first line is just generating example data. Not really relevant to the question. You could modify the filter function to do whatever test you want, e.g. `data.filter(x => x.url.indexOf('wdt') > -1)`. I was just going for the simplest possible example.

Comment: By the way, you could simplify your a wee bit by using [`url.includes('wdt')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) instead of indexOf.

Comment: I see... but my attempt to delete the found items is because I do not want to get includes 'wdt' or in your example 'foo' - I want those that don't include 'wdt'.

Comment: How could I get the opposite; something like '!!x.url.indexOf('wdt') > -1'?

Comment: So just negate the condition: `data.filter(x => !x.url.includes('wdt'))`

Answer (score 2):

This is not a solution but an explanation to why the code is not working as you expect

```
a = [a, b, c, d, e, f]

i=0 => a
i=1 => b
i=2 => c  ( now you decide to splice the array >> a = [a, b, d, e, f]
i=3 => e!  ( you missed the "d" cos it was shifted to the left
```

You should've `i--` every time you spliced the array